# File descriptors and O_CLOEXEC

Tags: c, file, operating-system, posix, system

I'm writing a very simple shell, which aims to provide greater extensibility to the programmer in terms of the options that they can make. Think, for example, making open flags available to specify. It is a hobby project, mostly for better learning C.

Is there ever any use case when a file descriptor (pipes, open files, etc.) should not have `O_CLOEXEC` except when it is standard input, output, or error (0, 1, 2) ? Would there be any use cases which make it desirable not to have O_CLOEXEC, unless the program has been written to expect additional file descriptors?

I am planning to automatically set the `O_CLOEXEC` for all file descriptors, so as not to worry about any file descriptor leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you don't write shell scripts that use file descriptors > 2 to pass extra file descriptors to sub shell scripts?

I do it all the time.

It's also a convenient trick to pass an extra file descriptor to something that will be invoked further down, such as a `find -exec` pipeline or something even more exotic.

Comment: Is there any use cases for doing the same for a pipe file descriptor, or can that safely be closed on exec?

Comment: @user129393192: I can make no sense of your comment.

Comment: Is there any reason a pipe file descriptor should not be `FD_CLOEXEC`?

Comment: @user129393192: Sounds like the normal case. I had to reach pretty far into the exotic to find a reason to set FD_CLOEXEC on a pipe.

Comment: How's that? If the duplicated file descriptor is passed to a child, you will have hangs or deadlocks ... due to `read` not returning `0` for example

Comment: @user129393192: What are you doing, writing a multithreaded shell? Normally you just close the wrong-side descriptors immediately after `fork()`.

Comment: Instead of doing that, I think that what I am suggesting would be a solution as well, to solely avoid those types of leaks. The shell needs to maintain the pipe until it has spawned the child, after the `fork` it is managing many descriptors, so this makes it more simple.